# ocaml function calling List.fold_left

Tags: ocaml

Fill in the skeleton given for pipe which uses List.fold_left to get an OCaml function
`val pipe : ('a -> 'a) list -> ('a -> 'a)`
such that `pipe [f1;...;fn]` (where `f1,...,fn` are functions!) returns a function `f` such that for any `x`, we have `f x` returns result `fn(...(f2(f1 x)))`.

Again, your task is to fill in the appropriate values for the folding function `f` and the base case.
Once you have implemented the function, you should get the following behavior at the OCaml prompt:

```
# pipe [] 3;;
- :  int =  3 
# pipe [(fun x -> x+x); (fun x -> x + 3)] 3 ;;
- :  int =  9 
# pipe [(fun x -> x + 3);(fun x-> x + x)] 3;;
- :  int =  12
```

Here is the code you need to fill in:

```
let pipe fs =
  let f a x = failwith "to be implemented" in
  let base = failwith "to be implemented" in
    List.fold_left f base fs
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: I think the usual rule for homework is that you should show some code that you've tried. Without something to comment on, it's hard to help without just solving the problem.

Comment: well I think it base should be let base = 0 in, but i'm not sure about the f part. how would i do that.

Answer (score 2):

In the skeleton you have given, `pipe` takes only one argument. From the type of pipe (`('a -> 'a) list -> 'a list`) you know that this argument has type `('a -> 'a) list`, and that you are supposed to return some value of type `('a -> 'a)`.

Now the type of `List.fold_left` is of the form `('b -> 'c -> 'b) -> 'b -> 'c list -> 'b`. But you know that:

1. It should return a value of type `'a -> 'a`, so `'b` will be instantiated with `('a -> 'a)` here
2. The third argument is of type `('a -> 'a) list`, so `'c list` will be `('a -> 'a) list` here: again `'c` will be instantiated with `('a -> 'a)`.

You can conclude that you will use `List.fold_left` at the specialized type (yes, it's a mouthful)

```
(('a -> 'a) -> ('a -> 'a) -> ('a -> 'a)) -> ('a -> 'a) -> ('a -> 'a) list -> ('a -> 'a)
```

Said shortly: if pipe must return a function and takes a list of functions, then `base` must itself be a function, and `f` must take two functions and return a function.

Which function should `base` be? `base` will be returned if `fs` is the empty list, so `base` should have the behavior expected of `pipe []`.

How should `f a x` combines the two functions `a` and `x`, both of type `'a -> 'a`, and return a single function `'a -> 'a`? I'll let you come up with an answer here. But the intuition you want to have the following equality to hold:

f (pipe [f1; f2]) f3  =  pipe [f1; f2; f3]

(It holds for any list rather than just `[f1; f2]`, but this example suffices). Working out the relation between the meaning of `pipe [f1; f2]` and `pipe [f1; f2; f3]`, you will be able to define the combining function `f`.

Note that you could have written the `pipe` function in a *very* different way starting from the following different skeleton:

```
let pipe fs x =
  let f a x = failwith "to be implemented" in
  let base = failwith "to be implemented" in
    List.fold_left f base fs
```

In this case, `pipe` takes two argument, one of type `('a -> 'a) list` and the other of type `'a`, and the whole returned value should be of type `'a` (a value, rather than a function). `f` takes a function (`'a -> 'a`) and a value (`'a`) and returns a value, and `base` is just a value (which one can you choose?).

I believe this second approach is slightly easier as a bit less abstract, but if you teacher asked you to use the first skeleton it is probably because it will teach you things about manipulating functions, and building functions that build functions.

Comment: let pipe fs =
  let f a x = a + x in
  let base = o in
    List.fold_left f base fs

Comment: this compiles fine but during the testing it's wrong, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: What you wrote makes no sense. Why would you even use addition in a polymorphic function supposed to work on any datatype `'a`, not just integers?

Comment: so i'm still confused, how would I do it then?

Comment: I suggest you try to get an answer for the questions in my post. I quote: "Which function should `base` be?"   "How should f a x combines the two functions [...]?"

Answer (score 0):

You might want to first answer those questions:

- Write an example of a call to pipe where only the base case is used.
- when is the base case used?
- What is the type of the base case?
- What would be better names for `f`, `a` and `x`, i.e. what is the role of those variables?